# Display name in Data Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'd like to know how to change the display name of a model, and customize error messages in Entity Framework. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required .... :")]
    [Display(Name = "Name Agency : ")]
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Nag
    {
        get
        {
            //code
        }
        set
        {
           //code
        }
    }
```

This is the code behind my form that adds data into my database. I've omitted irrelevant lines.

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("addcar", "Agence", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "search_form" }))
   { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dmcv) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dmcv) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dmcv) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Puisv) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Puisv) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Puisv) %>
        </div>

        // Similaire code

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: can you post your view, it would be helpful too

Comment: Why not try changing from using Edmx to DbContext Code Generation? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx Hope this helps.

Comment: @cubski the problem that i want to change dipslaye name, and error message i'm all ready using Data Entity framework(EDMx)

Comment: @Chlebta: did you try [DisplayName("Name Agency")] instead of [Display(Name = "Name Agency")] ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does `Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nag)` not show the error message you have specified in the `[Required(...)]` attribute when you leave the textbox empty? What message do you see instead?

Comment: The validation it works, but i want to change the Error message and Display Name.
@cubski thank's it works

Comment: @Chlebta: or [DataMemberAttribute(Name = "Name Agency")]

Comment: @Chlebta: What made it work for you? Also is the error message still now showing?

Comment: @cubski this ` [DisplayName("Name Agency")]` work fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change `[Display(Name = "Name Agency")]` to `[DisplayName("Name Agency")]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to reference this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

For changing the display name of the column, actually [Display(Name="Name Agency")] is OK. I'm using it in my projects.

For error message

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Required...")]
```

I read that it is possible that this won't work if you are using the entity framework designer because the designer overwrites your changes over and over then you will need to use the metadatatype something like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MetadataMyClass))]
public partial class myclass
{
}

//data annotations here
public class MetadataMyClass
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required...")]
  [Display(Name="Column Name")]
  public global:: System.String Nag
  {
    // ... etc, etc...
  }
}
```