# Entity Framework - change display name of tables/entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

As the title suggests, I was wondering if it's possible to change the display name of my tables across all of my application.. currently my tables from my DB have complicated names and was wondering if I can change the display name so that it's more user-friendly.

Is there a class I can create that would do that for me?

I've looked at the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107934/display-name-in-data-entity-framework)  but not sure if this applies to my scenario.. I'm new to EF :)

Thanks!

Additional Info:
I'm using the database first approach and currently have an EDMX setup.

Comment: Code-first or Database-first?  Meaning do you have an existing database or generating one from a class structure?

Comment: Do you have an EDMX built up?

Comment: @DStanley I have an existing database that I'm using (so I guess Database first?)

Comment: @Bob. yes I do have an EDMX build up and I've already coded and called entities based on it.. so I'm looking for something that I can use on top of what I have so far instead of having to rebuild code :)

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the table in your EDMX and just changing the name? The Designer.cs file will regenerate itself.

Comment: @Bob. I tried that. The name changed for the table but it did not propagate across the application to update the name of that same table in relationships.. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Code-first approach, you should check the answer from Vitor M. Barbosa. If you are using Database First (has an EDMX), you can achieve that by changing the Name of the table/entity in your diagram. Internal EF will map that name to the table in the database.

Comment: I believe this also changes the property name in the generated code - so code changes will need to be made, plus if the DisplayName contains characters that are not valid in a property name, then this method cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing code-first, you'll just need some [data annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958), e.g.:

```
[Table("TableName")]  
public class Table

[Column("BlogDescription", TypeName="ntext")]
public String Description {get;set;}
```