# How to get DataAnnotation Display Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have EF model class. for that I created `MetadataType` for that partial class.

Now I need to read or get all of these displayname of the properties of the object from c#. So I can use the in Excel Header row.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(vwGridMetadata))]
public partial class vwGrid
{

}

public class vwGridMetadata
{
    [Display(Name = "Note ID")]
    public int intNoteID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Global Number")]
    public string strGlobalLoanNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Data Source ID")]
    public Nullable<int> intDataSourceID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Sample ID")]
    ....
}
```

`vwGrid grd = new vwGrid;`

Here I want get all properties displayname in iteration. So I can add them to excel Header row and cells. How to do that?

Comment: Hi Friend, This question  is already answer find link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107934/display-name-in-data-entity-framework

Answer (score 14):

`Reflection` and `LINQ` is your friend

```
typeof(vwGridMetadata)
.GetProperties()
.Select(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>())
.Where(x => x != null)
.Select(x => x.Name);
```

**Note:** You need to include `System.Reflection` and `System.Linq` namespaces to your project in order to use these methods.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net Core 2 :

```
 var listOfFieldNames = typeof(vwGridMetadata)
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Select(f => f.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>())
                    .Where(x => x != null)
                    .Select(x=>x.Name)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
private string GetDisplayName(vwGridMetadata data, Object vwGridMetadataPropertie)
{
    string displayName = string.Empty;

    string propertyName = vwGridMetadataPropertie.GetType().Name;

    CustomAttributeData displayAttribute = data.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType.Name == "DisplayAttribute");

    if (displayAttribute != null)
    {
        displayName = displayAttribute.NamedArguments.FirstOrDefault().TypedValue.Value;
    }

    return displayName;
}
```

You can make a foreach to loop through vwGridMetadata class properties and call this method on each property, or just make a foreach inside and remove the Object argument from the method.